# React - how to change properties of a component in another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```
function DatTable() {
  return (
      <DataTable
          theme="dark"
          columns={columns}
          selectableRows
          data={FakeData}
      />
  );
};
```

I've called this component from another file in a dashboard

```
</Box>
  <DatTable></DatTable>
</Box>
```

Everything works properly if I change the properties in the original function. What I'm trying to achieve is set a useTheme hook for the component and for that I want to edit the theme inside of the dashboard like so :

```
</Box>
  <DatTable 
    theme="dark"
  ></DatTable>
</Box>
```

I've tried changing the properties inside of the dashboard component but it has no effects. I'm also unsure how to turn regular components into React components since the webpage goes white and breaks if I try it that way.

Comment: I suggest you use a context to if you need the changes to take place in the entire app https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you pass a theme prop to `<DatTable>` you need to extract it and then use it as a prop again in `<DataTable>`

```
function DatTable({theme}) {
  return (
      <DataTable
          theme={theme} 
          columns={columns}
          selectableRows
          data={FakeData}
      />
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Mohammed Shahed was half right but you need the curly brackets as well, otherwise it doesn't work. I've been trying to figure this out for so long.

Comment: If that seems a bit confusing you can always just have function DatTable(props) and then instead of theme={theme} you'll have theme={props.theme}. Also yes, @Mohammed Shahed answer is wrong as you have to extract them form the props object so you need those curly braces

Comment: Thanks, Could you also tell me how can i edit the properties when the component i'm using is returning: return (
          <CanvasJSChart options = {options}
                         onRef={ref => this.chart = ref}
          />
  When trying to edit onRef or options in the second component nothing changes with this either.

Comment: I would need to see more of what you mean and want to do cause I can't really understand right now. Meanwhile I'd appreciate it if you +1'd my answer or if you mark it as accepted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
// default data
let columns={};
let data={}

function DatTable(theme="dark", columns=columns, selectableRows='somedefaultdata',data=FakeData) {
  return (
      <DataTable
          theme=theme
          columns={columns}
          selectableRows
          data={FakeData}
      />
  );
};
```

Now

```js
<DatTable 
    theme="white"
/>
```

If you this now:

1. you don't need to send props at all.
2. If you send props those props will overwrite those default values